# Attempting to create an encryption program but variable seems to be resetting

Tags: python-3.x, encryption

I'm trying 2 get this code to work, my teacher wants me to encrypt this stuff so that it may use non alphabetic chr like "."(Haha! that quote thing looks like a golden snitch from Harry Potter!) I thought that making a dictionary w/ the chrs and their ascii values would work, it does for encrypt. but when I reversethe cipher and try to convert the chrs back, it doesn't work. I think a vriable is resetting, but idk where. Pls. Help.

```
 a_cipher = {
 ' ' : '32',
 '!' : '33',
 '"' : '34',
 '#' : '35',
 '$' : '36',
 '%' : '37',
 '&' : '38',
 "'" : '39',
 '(' : '40',
 ')' : '41',
 '*' : '42',
 '+' : '43',
 ',' : '44',
 '-' : '45',
 '.' : '46',
 '/' : '47',
 '0' : '48',
 '1' : '49',
 '2' : '50',
 '3' : '51',
 '4' : '52',
 '5' : '53',
 '6' : '54',
 '7' : '55',
 '8' : '56',
 '9' : '57',
 ':' : '58',
 ';' : '59',
 '<' : '60',
 '=' : '61',
 '>' : '62',
 '?' : '63',
 '@' : '64',
 'A' : '65',
 'B' : '66',
 'C' : '67',
 'D' : '68',
 'E' : '69',
 'F' : '70',
 'G' : '71',
 'H' : '72',
 'I' : '73',
 'J' : '74',
 'K' : '75',
 'L' : '76',
 'M' : '77',
 'N' : '78',
 'O' : ' ',     
 'P' : '!',     
 'Q' : '"',     
 'R' : '#',
 'S' : '$',
 'T' : '%',
 'U' : '&',     
 'V' : '86',
 'W' : '87',
 'X' : '88',
 'Y' : '89',
 'Z' : '90',
 '[' : '91',
 '\\' : '92' ,
 ']' : '93',
 '^' : '94',
 '_' : '95',
 '`' : '96',
 'a' : '97',
 'b' : '98',
 'c' : '99',
 'd' : '100',
 'e' : '101',
 'f' : '102',
 'g' : '103',
 'h' : '104',
 'i' : '105',
 'j' : '106',
 'k' : '107',
 'l' : '108',
 'm' : '109',
 'n' : '110',
 'o' : '111',
 'p' : '112',
 'q' : '113',
 'r' : '114',
 's' : '115',
 't' : '116',
 'u' : '117',
 'v' : '118',
 'w' : '119',
 'x' : '120',
 'y' : '121',
 'z' : '122',
 '{' : '123',
 '|' : '124',
 '}' : '125',}
reverse_cipher =  {v: k for k, v in a_cipher.items()}
def encrypt(s, direction):
    output = ""
    encryptme=""
    for ch in s:
          if direction == "encrypt":
           print('ch is '+ ch + ', a_cipher[ch] is '+ a_cipher[ch])
           encryptme = output + a_cipher[ch]
           print('output is ' + str(encryptme))
           print(encryptme)
          elif direction == "decrypt":
            output= output + reverse_cipher[encryptme]
            print('output is ' + str(output))                           
    return output
a=encrypt(input("Encrypt"),"encrypt")
encrypt(a,"decrypt")
```

HW Assignment:

Expanded Rotation Cipher
In each of the rotation cipher exercises thus far, you have translated the message into upper
case characters before encrypting it. This simplified the design of the cipher since only 26
characters needed to be rotated.
Many characters were not encrypted properly or at all. These included punctuation, numbers,
lower case letters, and many special characters ($ & # + and more).
In this program, you will create a new rotation cipher that will utilize a wider range of
characters. The assignment is to include all the displayable characters in the ASCII table
starting with a space “ ” through the right curly bracket }.
This rotation cipher must be designed to have the same primary benefit as Rot13 and should
be placed in the Crypto class. Modify your encrypt4.py program to call the new rotation
cipher. Save the new program as encrypt5D.py.
1. Encrypt the following message:
Han Solo reporting in, returning from Dagobah, leading Rebel forces with Ewoks to overtake
Death Star shield generator. Transmit all new orders via this secured channel.
2. Decrypt the following message:
|2CJO925O2O=:EE=6O=2>3[O=:EE=6O=2>3[O=:EE=6O=2>3]OO|2CJO925O2O=:EE=6O=2>3[O:E
DO7=6646OH2DOH9:E6O2DOD?@H]
Bonus (5 points): add capability in your cipher to properly handle ‘new line’ characters (ASCII
code 10).
Bonus (1 point): send one additional encrypted message to your instructor.
Email your encrypt5D.py file, your crypto.py file, and the output from 1. and 2. above to your
instructor. Copy and paste the output from 1. and 2. above into the email."

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid all this dictionnary. If you want the ASCII of a letter you can use ord(). In reverse you can use chr().

> chr(97) = 'a'.
>
> ord('a') = 97

After why don't you create 2 functions instead of 1 ( encrypt(s) and decrypt(code) )? This is easier to understand and you avoid a 'if' (which moreover is checked for every character in your case)

Last point, for the decrypt you won't be able to do it that way (in a simple way I mean). This is because the result of you string will be also a string and you won't be able easily to check if you have to keep 1, 2 or 3 characters.

> For example, 'Encrypt' encrypted with ord() gives 6911099114121112116

When you decrypt should you can split in an infinite way like :
6 - 9 - 110 - 99 - 11 - 41 -...
or
69 - 110 - 99 - 114 - 12 - 11 - ...
or
6 - 91 - 109 - 91 - 14 - ...

All those split won't provide the same output. To do that, you should take a look to Lexicographic tree's algorithme which are complex.

One solution is to create a elemnt to detect where to split (let's say #)

```
def encrypt(string):
    output = "#".join([str(ord(char)) for char in string])
    return output

def decrypt(code):
    code = [int(x) for x in code.split("#")]
    output = ""
    for num in code:
        output += chr(num)
    return output

s = 'Encrypt'
a = encrypt(s) 
print(a) # gives => 69#110#99#114#121#112#116
t = decrypt(a)
print(t)
```

***EDIT #1:***
And I forgot to replay to your answer -_-'
Variable doesn't reset but you are not using them 'properly'

In you 'for' loop you have :

```
encryptme = output + a_cipher[ch]
print('output is ' + str(encryptme))
```

When you enter the loop

> output = "" (and you never overwrite it)
>
> encryptme = "" + c (c = a_cipher[ch] = the letter encrypted)

encryptme changed for each loop as you never concatenate it.

If you do :

```
encryptme = encryptme  + c #(c = a_cipher[ch])
```

Every loop, encryptme will take is own value and the new piece of code. This can also be written :`encryptme += c`

***EDIT #2*** 
Your question is what we call Caesar algorithm which can be done that way :

```
def caesar(s, offset):
    a = [(ord(char) + offset)%255 for char in s]
    output = ""
    for num in a:
        output += chr(num)
    return output

print(caesar('code', 13)) # => VbWX
```

***EDIT #3:***
With the complete exercice I ended up with :

```
def caesar_encrypt(s, offset):
    output = ""
    up_limit = max(ord('}'), ord(' '))
    down_limit = min(ord('}'), ord(' '))
    for char in s:
        #if the element in included in the list of valid character
        if up_limit >= ord(char) >= down_limit:
            new_char = chr(ord(char) + offset) # Shift
            output += new_char
        else:
            output += char

    return output

def caesar_decrypt(s, offset):
    output = ""
    up_limit = max(ord('}'), ord(' '))
    down_limit = min(ord('}'), ord(' '))
    for char in s:
        # if the character was included before the offset in the range of element possible to shift
        if up_limit >= ord(char) + offset >= down_limit:
            new_char = chr(ord(char) + offset)
            output += new_char
        else:
            output += char

    return output

s = 'Han Solo reporting in, returning from Dagobah, leading Rebel forces with Ewoks to overtake Death Star shield generator'
print(s)
print(caesar_encrypt(s, 13))
i = '|2CJO925O2O=:EE=6O=2>3[O=:EE=6O=2>3[O=:EE=6O=2>3]OO|2CJ‌​O925O2O=:EE=6O=2>3[O‌​:E DO7=6646OH2DOH9:E6O2DOD?@H]'
print(i)
print(caesar_decrypt(i, -13))
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't look fine as the encrypted solution doesn't provide something logical.

NB :  we cannot use string.maketrans() as expected at the first sight

I hope it helps,

Comment: Thx, that helps alot, how can I make it so that it converts it into ascii, adds 13, than turns it back to a character? I need it that way to go with my school instructions. I need to decrypt this:|2CJO925O2O=:EE=6O=2>3[O=:EE=6O=2>3[O=:EE=6O=2>3]OO|2CJO925O2O=:EE=6O=2>3[O:E
DO7=6646OH2DOH9:E6O2DOD?@H]

Comment: I replied in Edit 2 because the code is not looking nice on a comment :D

Comment: i think i'm doing something wrong, when I put in the code and then put -13 to decrypt, I get this: o%6=B,%(B%B0-880)B0%1&NB0-880)B0%1&NB0-880)B0%1&PBBo%6=B,%(B%B0-880)B0%1&NB-87B*0))')B;%7B;,-8)B%7B723;P

Comment: I've tried several offsets on you code (from -32 to +32) and I don't find any sentence 'logical'. Can you paste your exercice ? I'm not sure you have to apply Caesar algorithm

Comment: Oh I see now, It's not exactly what we were doing... In such case we can use another function of **string** library called maketrans. I'll try to find it in an easyway